# how to connect to azure database for mysql, from azure app service with wordpress docker image?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure app service, using the [latest wordpress image from docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress). The screenshot for the azure app service:
[image]

Then in the azure app service -> application setting, I added the following key/value pairs which will be used to connect Azure database for mysql:

1. WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
2. WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
3. WORDPRESS_DB_PASSSWORD
4. WORDPRESS_DB_USER

screenshot:
[image]

Inside my Azure database for mysql, I have enabled public access / allow public access from any azure service / also add my client ip and this ip range 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255. I can access it from my client and create the database which will be used by azure app service. Screenshot like below:
[image]

in server parameters, I also turn off the require_secure_transport setting:
[image]

At last, I tried to launch the site, but it throws the error "Error establishing a database connection", screenshot below:
[image]

I'm new to wordpress / docker, and don't know how to fix this issue. I also reviewed some videos / docs, and didn't see any other configuration differences. Could you please guide me how to fix this issue? Thanks very much.

Comment: have you checked the generated wp-config values? To see if they match your database and environment settings?

Comment: @Mtxz, I checked, there is no wp-config in the image. Instead, there is a file  wp-config-docker.php, and it has some code like this: define( 'DB_NAME', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_NAME', 'wordpress') );  so I think they match.

Comment: after enabling WORDPRESS_DEBUG, the error messge shows like that: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'ivan'@'52.xx.xxx.xx' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1753
Access denied for user 'ivan'@'52.xxx.xx.xxx' (using password: YES). But I can connect to this sql from my client.

Comment: At least we know that the issue is not on the network lever as it seems you have the denied mysql response. So you can connect to the server using the same user (Ivan) and password as the WP ones? Does ivan MySQL user has any IP restriction? Are you sure you local client don't use SQL over SSH: is it a direct 3306 connection? Can you check MySQL logs?

Comment: Can you check if the user was granted access? ```USE wordpress ``` ```SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ivan'@'%'```

Answer (score 3):

You received this error message.

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045)>: Access denied for user 'ivan'@'52.xx.xxx.xx' (using password: YES)

It means MySQL received, processed, and rejected your WordPress instance's attempt to connect. So you know the hostname is right and your cloud provider's firewall settings allow your WordPress instance to exchange network data with your MySQL instance.

What's wrong?

MySQL's user name / account name setup has a quirk. An account name can look like `'ivan'@'localhost'` or `'ivan'@'%'` (or even something like `'ivan'@'192.0.22.33'`).

The first of those only allows login from localhost (or via tunneling via ssh). The second allows login from `'%'`, meaning any host. You need the second one for your WordPress instance to get access to MySQL.

When you're logged in to MySQL from your machine, do this.

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user WHERE user='ivan';
```

You should see two rows, like these

```
 host       user  
 ----       ---   
 %          ivan  
 localhost  ivan
```

It's possible the account with `'%'` as the host is missing. If so that means you need to [create another MySQL account and give it access to your database](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql). Do that like this.

```sql
CREATE USER 'ivan'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Next, make sure the user account you just created -- the one your WordPress software will use to connect to MySQL -- has access to your database.

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'ivan'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you still get the error message, it's possible the password on your `'ivan'@'%'` account doesn't match what you put into your WordPress configuration.  You can change it with

```sql
ALTER USER 'ivan'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If it still gives the same error message, it's possible that your cloud vendor requires TLS to connect to MySQL.  You may want to consult their support team about that.

(This is a common stumbling block setting up new WordPress instances.)

Answer (score 0):

ok just to keep and make things clear. all IPs can connect to the DB but are you actually authorized to read/write date in the DB?

I.E. this might be a permission/privilege issue.
I suggest double checking user privileges and determine who can do what on your DB

Best Regards. :-)